# EC2 server in VPC stops responding after joining domain

Tags: amazon-ec2, active-directory, amazon-vpc

We have a EC2 Windows Server set up and running in our VPC, connected to our network via a Juniper 5GT.  This is working well, with the tunnel up and stable.

If I then join the server to our local domain, it appears to work - I can then log on using domain credentials, and use domain accounts when applying security to folders etc.

After I log out, if I give it around an hour, the box becomes unresponsive.  I can't ping it, although a tracert goes all the way barring the last hop - so the tunnel is ok.  I can't RDP into it.  If I reboot it, then it works for a while before doing the same thing.

Un-joining it from the domain fixes the problem, and it stays up and stable.  The event logs don't show anything obvious, at least to me.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to this, or am at least 90% confident that I have.
The server in question had TFS 2010 installed on it before it was joined to the domain, and has not been reinstalled / updated (yet) since the machine was joined to the domain.

I started noticing Event Log errors relating to TFS services trying to find our domain, specifically [TF200035](http://billwg.blogspot.com/2008/12/tfs-service-account-requires-read.html) events (that's the detail; event log shows it as 3071).  These relate to the hourly TFS AD replication.  Since our instance was dying after about an hour, that seemed like a good place to start looking.
I disabled the following two services:

- Visual Studio Team Foundation Build Service Host
- Visual Studio Team Foundation Background Job Agent

...and the instance has been solid ever since.
I've got no idea why this would cause the instance to become unresponsive, but next step is likely a reinstall of TFS, along with some finger-crossing.